# Im trying to get users input in Bash

Tags: git-bash, bash-completion

I need a command that can ask the user for input and do something with the resuld such as run if they answer with a specific result.

I tried
`read -p`
and i cant get input to work and i despretly need it

Answer (score 0):

Heare is a solution

```
echo "read some text"
read text

echo '${text}'
```

this read a input as text then save it to a varible and the output it.

https://github.com/G4lile00/Shell-Script

Here's my github with some sh scripts.